# How is console.log() implemented?

Tags: javascript, console.log

Where can I learn about the implementations of console.log? To be clear, I know HOW to use console.log(), but I want to see the underlying implementations of console.log for some of the major browsers. Does console.log just echo input back into a part of the screen? Does it save logged strings to disk when parsing js and then write it to back to the screen? etc.

Comment: In Chromium/blink/sources/devtools clone git https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink

Comment: Found a mirror of something relevant - https://github.com/mirrors/blink/blob/2a84c93ef883193ffb64e5d8e1face6cb33a47f7/Source/devtools/front_end/sdk/ConsoleModel.js#L107 , if I may ask, _why_ do you need this information? It's just a DOM element that has text appended to in JS, there's the CodeMirror editor in the background.

Comment: I'm curious if writing to console actually writes to disk or if it's all done in-memory.

Comment: For what browser? Also, just the input or also the output?

Comment: Any of the major three browsers. I noticed that IE doesn't seem to display my console logging unless I have console open, but Chrome will display my console logs even if the console window wasn't initially open - which made me curious about how the console logging is implemented (either the input or the output).

Comment: Well, I linked you to the chrome/safari source, I can link you to the FF one, but I'm afraid I can't do the same for IE - you'd have to mail the guys at IEBlog and ask.

Answer (score 1):

All Console behaviour (including the algorithms that must be implemented) are defined in https://console.spec.whatwg.org (and if it's not in there, officially, its implementation is undefined and literally "whatever works").

For this question specifically, the behaviour [as of 23 March 2021](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer) is prescribed as:

> If the console is not open when the printer operation is called, implementations should buffer messages to show them in the future up to an implementation-chosen limit (typically on the order of at least 100).

(Although of course IE is no longer nearly as relevant in 2021 as it was back in 2014, with the very last version of IE finally entering EOL on June 15, 2022)

Comment: (Also, yes, this is a particularly poorly written spec, reading more like an initial working draft. It is what it is)

Answer (score -2):

console.log() can be used to debug variables, test if functions are being called, things along those lines, here's an example

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  console.log(i)
}
```

console:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

1 more example:

```
function start(){
  console.log("starting...")
  started = true
  console.log(started)
}
```

console:
"starting..."
true

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking. They want to know how it's implemented, not how it's used.

Answer (score -5):

I don't think this is part of any specification. You can read that and the related links : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log

Comment: This isn't what OP was asking for.

Comment: He specifically said he knows how to use it, he is asking about where it is implemented.

Comment: And yet this is part of the answer because it says it's browser specific. For instance, this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console is a bit more thorough and is accessible from my first link...

Comment: That's _still_ not he asked for. He is asking for how it's implemented, your link is irrelevant even for Firefox.

Comment: This is a more correct link for what OP was asking for by the way http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/base/nsConsoleService.cpp#162